# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, cross-origin-read-blocking

I want to use **chart.js** but im getting this error anyone willing to help me solve the problem?

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Here is my js.

```
const Chart = document.getElementById("lineChart");
console.log(Chart);

let lineChart = new Chart(Chart,{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]}
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you importing the js?
Are you using 
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Im using this  <script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

Based on comment, You are importing the html page and not the js file.

Here is what you can do to resolve the issue.

After visiting https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js you can,

1. Select the version of build that you want.
2. Select the type of asset that you want (Javascript / Stylesheet).
3. Click on '</>' to copy the script tag which can be pasted and used directly in your page.

[image: Snipshot]

Comment: Hi there! @Nik Now its not displaying?

Comment: What is not displaying? I did not get it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The chart is not displaying on my website. I dont know why? There's no error in the console. @Nik

Comment: Can you add the code snippet where this issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I dont have a snippet for the code but i have this. [Code](https://pastebin.com/UuXtbXCG)